# Can't get html form to work with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I cannot for the life of me get this simple form to work...

What's wrong?

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="kupongkode" placeholder=" Kupongkode?"> <input
        type="submit" value="&#x2713;" id="kupongkodeKnapp">
</form>

<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ['kupongkodeKnapp'] )) {
    if ($_POST ['kupongkode'] == "TEST")
        echo "Godkjent!";

    else
        echo "Ikke godkjent";
}

?>
```

Comment: `isset ( $_POST ['kupongkodeKnapp'] )` is always false.

Comment: It's the **names** of the form elements that become the keys in `$_POST`, not the **IDs**. Your submit button is missing a name.

Comment: Thanks, I see that I've written "id" instead of "name"... Stupid mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the name attribute on your submit is missing

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="kupongkode" placeholder=" Kupongkode?">
        <input type="submit" value="&#x2713;" name="kupongkodeKnapp" id="kupongkodeKnapp">
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset ( $_POST ['kupongkodeKnapp'] )) {
        if ($_POST ['kupongkode'] == "TEST")
            echo "Godkjent!";
        else
            echo "Ikke godkjent";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

On form submissions you always want to reference form elements by the "name" attribute". This is the case for the frontend (JavaScript) and backend (PHP or other).

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ['kupongkode'] )) {
if ($_POST ['kupongkode'] == "TEST")
    echo "Godkjent!";
else
    echo "Ikke godkjent";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the name of your submit button has to be the same when you check it with `isset`

You should go through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) link.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake, you should use `name` instead of `id`:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="kupongkode" placeholder=" Kupongkode?"> <input
        type="submit" value="&#x2713;" name="kupongkodeKnapp">
</form>

<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ['kupongkodeKnapp'] )) {
    if ($_POST ['kupongkode'] == "TEST")
        echo "Godkjent!";

    else
        echo "Ikke godkjent";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="kupongkode" placeholder=" Kupongkode?"> 
<input type="submit" value="&#x2713;" id="kupongkodeKnapp">
 </form>
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST)){
if ($_POST ['kupongkode'] == "TEST")
    echo "Godkjent!";

else
    echo "Ikke godkjent";
}

?>
```